# How to change the text of a li tag?

Tags: jquery

I have a li tag as shown below

```
<li  class="favoriterestbtnname btn btn-mrn">Home</li>



var facvnamebefore = $('.favoriterestbtnname').val();
alert(facvnamebefore);
$(".favoriterestbtnname").text("new value");
var facvnameafter = $('.favoriterestbtnname').val();
alert(facvnameafter);
```

I was trying to change the text of it dynamically , but this is giving me value as 0

My fiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/4fnprzpu/1/

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use *text* instead of *val* to get the value of the tag.

```
var facvnamebefore = $('.favoriterestbtnname').text();
```

*Val* function is to input tags.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

write .text() instead of .val()..

```
var facvnamebefore = $('.favoriterestbtnname').text();

alert(facvnamebefore);

$(".favoriterestbtnname").text("new value");

var facvnameafter = $('.favoriterestbtnname').text();


alert(facvnameafter);
```

**Updated fiddle** :-

http://jsfiddle.net/4fnprzpu/2/

Extra Information :-

As documented in [official site](http://api.jquery.com/text/) :-

> .text() :- Get the combined text contents of each element in the set
>   of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text
>   contents of the matched elements.
>
> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** instead **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".favoriterestbtnname").text("one");
});
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/81ysodw1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Javascript.

```
<script>
  const oldText="LI TAG TEXT";
  document.write(
    '<li id=liId onClick="changeText(this.id)">'+oldText+'</li>'
  );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
const stat=[oldText,"NEW LI TAG TEXT"];
let   cptr=0;

function changeText(button_id){
   var el = document.getElementById(button_id);

   el.textContent = stat[cptr^=1];

// or       el.firstChild.data = stat[cptr^=1];

// or       el.innerHTML = stat[cptr^=1];
}
</script>
```